# transpose a table and data

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy data from SAP into a table, I can copy them but the table moves to the right.

```
  Sub StartExtract()
  Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose (X)
' Set the sid and client to connect to
  W_System = "P10320"
' Run the GUI script
  RunGUIScript
' End the GUI session
  objSess.EndTransaction

 ' Switch to the worksheet where the data is loaded to
   Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose (BGSOCIAL)
   Sheets("BGSOCIAL").Select

' Load the CSV file
  OpenCSVFile


' Update the time and date on the control worksheet
  Sheets("Extraction").Select
  Cells(2, 2).Value = Now()
```

I think it's that part of the code that's a problem.

I would like to copy them inside the table

[image: the data is copied next to it]

- another part of the code

  ```
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
   "TEXT;" & fpath & "\" & ffilename, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
   .Name = "text"
   .FieldNames = True
   .RowNumbers = False
   .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
   .PreserveFormatting = True
   .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
   .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
   .SavePassword = False
   .SaveData = True
   .AdjustColumnWidth = True
   .RefreshPeriod = 0
   .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
   .TextFilePlatform = 850
   .TextFileStartRow = 1
   .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
   .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
   .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
   .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
   .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
   .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
   .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
   .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
   .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
   .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
   .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  ```

  End With

Comment: I recomment reading this too: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: have you solved it

Comment: @AAA Hello, always the same problem.

Comment: Your code doesn't show where you have the copy issues

Comment: @AAA I put another part of the code.